# QT C++ How to detect QSerialPort plugged out?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am transferring data with QSerialPort. When my USB device is plugged out. If my Serial Port is open, I want to close it.
Before connecting to the serial port, I check the devices connected with getAvailiblePorts().

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  QList<QSerialPortInfo> test = serial.getAvailiblePorts();
   QStringList myDevices;

    if(test.isEmpty()){
        qDebug()<<"Empty";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Not Empty";

    }

}
```

With my button function above, I plug in the usb and press the button. It tells me it is not empty. Then I remove the usb and try again, it tells me it's empty.

Then I opened the serial port connection and removed the usb. My serial port stays open even though the usb is not plugged in. Although no usb device is connected, when the button is pressed, the father gives the information that it is not empty.

How can I close Serial Port when usb plugged out?

Comment: Side note: you really ought to avoid using the "magic" "on_" functions. 1) they use the old runtime connect functionality. 2) they are not type safe. Use the modern type safe signal/slot connections instead - available since Qt 5.

Comment: Try to handle [`QSerialPort::errorOccurred`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qserialport.html#errorOccurred) signal